# Questions regarding pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

1. If p is a pointer (say `int * p`), then what does `[p]` means ?
   Also what does `4[p]` means ? (i.e. multiplying a scalar with [p] )
2. Suppose xyz is some data type defined by in the program.
   Then what does the

   ```
   void (*xyz)(void);
   ```

   statement mean?

Comment: please don't ask several questions at once and provide a proper question title. Your first question is answered in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a

Answer (score 6):

1. `4[p]` means the same as `p[4]`.  See e.g. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html.
2. If `xyz` is already a data type, then that's an error.  If not, then it's the definition of a function pointer called `xyz`.  Assuming that you meant "`void`" not "`coid`", then [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*xyz%29%28void%29) tells us:

   > declare xyz as pointer to function (void) returning void

Comment: Strictly speaking, (2) asks for the meaning of the statement. I.e. something like "it's a declaration statement"...

Comment: Also, if `xyz` is a data type, then the 2nd declaration statement is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

if `p` is defined as `int *p`  then

`[p]` is wrong! cause an error: expected expression before `‘[’` token.

Where as `0[p]` is correct!

And `0[p]` is same as  `p[0]` , similarly `p[4]`  is `4[p]`.

compiler convert `p[4]` into `*(p + 4)`  that as   `*(4 + p)`  => `4[p]`

**Additionally**, suppose if you have *an array* say `int a[10]`, you can access elements of array either as `a[i]` or `i[a]`

following example will be useful, *I think*:

```
int main(){
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int* p;  // similar declaration of p (you asked)
    p = a;
    int i= 0; 
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("a[i] =  %d  and i[a] = %d \n",a[i],i[a]);
    }
    printf(" using p \n"); // access using pointer.  
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("p[i] =  %d  and i[p] = %d \n",p[i],i[p]);
    }
}
```

compile and execution:

```
:~$ ./a.out 
a[i] =  1  and i[a] = 1 
a[i] =  2  and i[a] = 2 
a[i] =  3  and i[a] = 3 
a[i] =  4  and i[a] = 4 
a[i] =  5  and i[a] = 5 
 using p 
p[i] =  1  and i[p] = 1 
p[i] =  2  and i[p] = 2 
p[i] =  3  and i[p] = 3 
p[i] =  4  and i[p] = 4 
p[i] =  5  and i[p] = 5
```

**[ANSWER-2 ]**

A declaration `void (*xyz)(void);`  creates `xyz` a pointer to function that returns `void` and arguments are `void`. (`xyz` is not a data-type but a pointer variable) e.g.

```
void function(void){
 // definition 
}

void (*xyz)(void);
```

then `xyz` can be assigned address of `function`:

```
xyz = function;
```

And using `xyz()` you can call `function()`,  A example for `void (*xyz)(void)`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(void){
    printf("\n An Example\n");
} 
int main(){
    void (*xyz)(void);   
    xyz = function;    
    xyz();
}
```

Now compile and execute it:

```
:~$ gcc  x.c
:~$ ./a.out 

 An Example
:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

> what does `[p]` mean?

Nothing in itself.

> Also what does `4[p]` mean?

Due to pointer arithmetic, `4[p]` means `*(4 + p)`, which is, given that addition is commutative, equivalent to `*(p + 4)`, which in turn can be written as `p[4]`, i. e. it's the 5th element of an array pointed to by `p`.

> If `xyz` is a data type, then what does `void (*xyz)(void);` statement mean?

It's a syntax error then.

If `xyz` is not a data type, then it declares `xyz` to be a function pointer taking and returning `void` (i. e. "nothing").

Answer (score 2):

1) 4[p] means the same as p[4] both of which essentially mean *(p+4) which means the 5th element from the start of the array `p`.

2) `xyz` is the type of a pointer to a function that takes a no arguements and returns nothing.

```
typedef void (*xyz)(void);    

void func();

xyz f= func;
```

It could also be the function pointer itself if used in the below fashions

```
//imagine the above typedef is omitted.

void (*xyz)(void) = func;

void (*xyz)(void);  // uninitialized pointer.
```